# Usar ajax en cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Hola a todos como están verán tengo una función dentro de mi controlador AdvertisementsController algo asi

```
public function listsize($article = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $query_sizes = $this->ArticlesSizes->find('list',['conditions'=>['id_article' => $article]]);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->set('sizes',$query_sizes);
    }

}
```

el resultado de ello lo quiero llevar en una funcion de ajax en jquery algo asi

```
$("#id_article").change(function(){
   var id = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        url: "<?php echo Router::Url(['controller' =>'Advertisements','Action'=>'listsize'])?>",
        data:{id:id},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
   });
  });
```

Pero me sale este error

```
toolbar.js:90 GET http://192.168.1.26:8080/nuevostyle/Advertisements/%3C?php%20echo%20Router:…dvertisements%27,%27Action%27=%3E%27listsize%27])?%3E&id=2&_=1472490466544 404 (Not Found)
```

en la consola no se si este haciendo bien o que me falte Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿pudiste resolverlo?. Tengo dudas acerca de la utilización de ajax en cakephp3 y quisiera ponerme en contacto contigo.

Comment: Si pude resolverlo pues si necesitas contactarme entra ami perfil o envía un mensaje

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer en tu archivo js en el atributo url no te esta interpretando el codigo php, intenta poner la ruta directamente, ejemplo:

```
 url: "http://192.168.1.26:8080/nuevostyle/Advertisements/listsize"
```